# Does this .NET tool/utility exist?

Tags: class, vsto, diagram

When I generate a Class Diagram using VS2008, say for a C# file XYZ.cs - I get a Class Diagram detailing all the Fields,Properties,Methods and Nested Types.

Is there a tool/utility, which will do the same for all the internal Class/Interface references I have used within this file.

For eg. I have a Property of the type ABC in XYZ.cs ...is there any way to get to show ABC and related reference on the class diagram of XYZ itself?

To be more precise: If my XYZ.cs has a property Biped of the type Mammal. The class diagram displays and lists Biped...what I would like to see is Mammal also listed as a hierarchical node in the diagram itself.

To put it simply the complete object tree for all types...for atleast the user defined types.

Comment: internal class means.do you want to see MLSI code ?

Comment: No..not MLSI code ...I think Rado(below) gets what I am pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the property and choose "Show as Association"
2. Repeat for all properties with different classes

Comment: Cool...but is there a global setting to show this always by default?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can try this: http://www.codeplex.com/modeling  

The reason they don't do it by default is that there will be too many classes in the designer

Answer (score 0):

[Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/download/umodel/uml_tool_enterprise.html) or [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/). Both applications can reverse-engineer C# and Java code into UML diagrams, including class diagrams. To do this, they analyse the sourcecode or assemblies of your project.

I have used both but prefer UModel because it has less functionality. !!! EA is just overkill since it has a lot of other functionality related to project management, bug tracking and a lot more. Unfortunately, EA doesn't always allow you to undo certain actions. With UModel, you can always undo your mistakes and the user interface is more user-friendly, in my opinion.