# Visual Studio 2008 class diagram with more detail?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am looking for a tool like (or that is) Visual Studio's class diagram generator, but with more detail.

Currently the class diagram will show a hierarchical overview of the classes and inheritance. So say there are three classes layed out as such

`BaseClass` -> `GeneralClass : BaseClass` -> `SpecificClass : GeneralClass`

Visual Studio will show this nicely in a tree structure in the class diagram.

What I want to see is the classes each of those classes reference.

So say `GeneralClass` instantiates and uses a class of type `GeneralClassWorkerThread`, I want that to be listed in the class diagram too. I don't want to just a inheritance tree, but more of a using/utilizing tree?

Is there anything like this out there? Can Visual Studio do this itself?

At the very least, what would the name of such a graph be so I can continue my search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only taken a few weeks but I finally found something usable from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401484/does-this-net-tool-utility-exist).

Specifically [Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/download/umodel.html), load a visual studio project file and it will do the rest. It cost $ but has a free trial period which is more than enough to just generate a graph as described in the OP.

This could be done with reflection but it proved to be a overbearing given the amount of information that can be gained via reflection.